# ActionScript Worker applicationStorageDirectory

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, worker

I am trying to save data to a file with an ActionScript Worker for an iOS/Android Flex mobile app. Before using a Worker, I simply used `File.applicationStorageDirectory`. When testing locally, my main app returns something like `C:\Users\myself\AppData\Roaming\com.mycompany.myapp\Local Store\` but within a Worker it saves it to `C:\Users\myself\AppData\Roaming\[Worker].null\Local Store\`.

How can I access the applicationStorageDirectory of the parent SWF within my Worker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass it correct `path` from main thread.

How do you create a Worker?

Comment: This is the solution I ended up going with. I was hoping to avoid it because it meant I had to refactor quite a bit in my database classes to use the passed in path rather than the applicationStorageDirectory